# Programming with VBA in Excel to copy and paste under specific conditions and loop

Tags: database, vba, excel

Im new to all that is programming and recently I've been tasked with the completion of a database for a project in my college, the database itself is just a registry of the fishing that some fishermen do and I have to complete it with things like gender, working zona and registry number which is found in the same database. I've been reading a lot about VBA programming and searched previous questions here on stackoverflow but couldn't piece it all together

What I want Excel to do is basically this

1. Find an empty cell (lets say in the Gender column)
2. Copy the names corresponding with that cell's entry (same row)
3. Find the names coincidence in which the gender cell is not empty
4. Copy that
5. Paste it on the empty cell
6. If it doesn't find a name coincidence paste an X on the empty cell
7. And finally repeat until there are no more empty cells

I'm working in Microsoft Office 2013, and I know I'm pretty much asking for the whole thing to be done, but is my fist approach and I'm not making any progress 
Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly learn how to record a macro, this will help generate lot of code by itself also easiest way to learn. (Try using filter to find out the empty cell)

Now you just need to extrapolate the generated code to make a loop and customise it to your requirement.